# KeyBoard is not appear while entering text into TextField

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

As you can see into screenShot when I am entering any text into text field keyboard doesn't pop-up so can anyBody tell me how can I solve this problem. And I am using xCode 6.1 beta version.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click simulator go to Hardware->keyboard->Toggle Software Keyboard[image]